# Run Callback On Main Thread

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have some code that interacts with the Android Facebook SDK, Asynchronously. Unfortunately this means when it returns it is in a background thread.

Cocos-2dx prefers me to interact with it in the Main Thread, especially when doing things like telling the Director to switch scenes (As it involves Open GL)

Is there any way to get some code to run on the Main thread ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As long as you have a Context, you can do something like this:

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
```

And to run code on UI thread:

```
mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run code
    }
});
```

As suggested by [kaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/779123/kaka):

You could also use the static [Looper.getMainLooper()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper%28%29) which

> Returns the application's main looper, which lives in the main thread of the application.

Comment: You could also use the static [Looper.getMainLooper()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper()) which _"Returns the application's main looper, which lives in the main thread of the application."_.

Comment: @kaka Cool, did not know that, it has now been added to the answer :)

Comment: post doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: @PredragManojlovic any reference? According to the documentation it does https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: @cYrixmorten My mistake. There is also Handler in another package so I've made wrong import. Up-voting this.

Comment: @PredragManojlovic alright :) but thanks for the heads up anyways, if it was the case an update of the answer would be required.

Comment: @fnc12 I think it may be easier to have the Java code return control to cocos2d-x on the main thread rather than try to jump onto the main thread in C++

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 12):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //execute code on main thread
    }
});
```

Comment: Also true but runOnUiThread is only available within Activity and Fragment classes

Answer (score 5):

In C++:

```
Director::getInstance()->getScheduler()->performFunctionInCocosThread([]{
    // execute code on main thread
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run code in the main thread in this 2 ways: (with Java 8's lambdas)

If you have an activity instance:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
     // do your work on main thread
});
```

Otherwise use an Handler object and post a Runnable.

You can use the `postDelayed` version if you need some delay before executing the code.

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
 handler.post(() -> {
     // do your work on main thread
 });
```