# Why is my app suspending threads and how can I fix this?

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my code:

```
public class CustomSwipeAdaptor extends PagerAdapter {

    private int[] image_resources={R.drawable.aa,R.drawable.bb,R.drawable.cc};
    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomSwipeAdaptor(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image_resources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View item_view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
        container.addView(item_view);
        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}


public class Chapter1 extends AppCompatActivity{

    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomSwipeAdaptor adaptor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chapter1);
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adaptor=new CustomSwipeAdaptor(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adaptor);
    }


}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
06-12 18:45:05.631 341-349/com.example.kips.itapps W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.170ms 
06-12 18:45:27.677 341-349/com.example.kips.itapps W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.168ms 
06-12 18:47:31.577 341-349/com.example.kips.itapps W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.052ms 
06-12 18:48:36.275 341-349/com.example.kips.itapps W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.650ms 
06-12 18:56:21.208 341-349/com.example.kips.itapps W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.523ms
```

Comment: What makes you think that these warnings represent a problem to be solved?

Comment: If you remove the line `imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);`, the warning disappears?

Comment: @CommonsWare: At least in my code, they appear to correlate with all threads not getting work done for extended periods of time >1000ms, even though each logcat line says it only paused for 9ms.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely harmless. From [here](https://plus.google.com/wm/4/+JensHohl/posts/1TADDCRZB1r)

> The heap for Java code is a shared resource. For the GC pause in ART,
>   threads must be suspended so they aren't changing the heap and
>   breaking GC invariants. To suspend threads a thread local variable is
>   modified by the GC and then the threads observe this change and
>   relinquish the mutator lock, the GC will then hold the lock
>   exclusively and run. As threads are suspended whilst other threads
>   relinquish their share of the mutator lock, its important for jank
>   that threads respond in a timely manner. 5ms is nearly 1/3rd of a 16ms
>   frame and so ART warns when thread suspension is slow. As +Aladin
>   Q​says this may happen with a lot of load. If its happening
>   frequently, or without load, it may be evidence of a bug that may
>   cause jank.

Unless you have serious problems preventing your app from accomplishing its goals, it is benign, along with [several other similar log outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652766/suspending-all-threads-took-ms-warning-using-threads-android).

Comment: Gist: Suspending the threads isn't the point of the warning. The point is that it's slow.